# Hibernate Mapping JPA Collections

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I want to do a pretty simple thing but can't get it to work.

I have ab entity Game and an Entity Player. Every Game should have two foreign keys from Players. And it works, but there is one catch: I cant assign the same foreign key from Player to multiple Game-entities. Where is this constraint coming from, and how can I tell him to not do that?

I'm using Hibernate and JPA. My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence" version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="PlayerService" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="********"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="********"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://********"/>          
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>        
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'm getting the entitymanager per:

```
util = new JPAUtil();
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PlayerService");
em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
```

in my Games-Entity:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass=Player.class)
private Collection<Player> player;
```

and there is Player-Entity.

Am I doing this entirely wrong?

---

```
@Entity
public class Game {

    @Id
    int gameid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="game")
    private Collection<TestPlayer> test;
}

@Entity
public class TestPlayer {

@Id
int id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="gameid")
private Game game;
}
```

Comment: When you say I cant, do you get any errors when you assign foreign key? If yes show us the error.

Comment: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "..."
  Detail: Key (player_playerid)=(1) already exists.

As said, this is not intented, because many games may have the same player.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the error to get the proper answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try an `OneToMany` relationship instead of `ElementCollection`.
I think that in an `ElementCollection` the elements (`Player`) belongs to the `Game` and therefore Hibernate doesn't let you assign it to multiple `Games`

in your Game Entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="game")
private Collection<Player> player;
```

in your Player entity:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="game_id")
private Game game;
```

for reference: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association

Comment: This throws this:
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.sc2tube.entities.beans.Player column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: The exception is pretty descriptive. Are you trying to use column `id` twice? Could you edit and post your `Player` entity?

Comment: I cleaned a lot now, and now he at least doesnt throw an error. But now he forgets the mapping of the player to the game. Now it looks like this (edit: moved it to the start post)

Comment: Sorry I've reread your post and your comments and I think you will need a `ManyToMany` relationship because a Player can have multiple Games and a Game multiple players. This kind of relationship is more complex and requires a third table (Player_Game) for the relationship. Please refer to the docs for more details. Anyway your mapping must work if you associate the Player to only one Game...

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks like this was the problem. I knew it would be something trivial. @ManyToMany works for anyone having the same problem.